# How to change brightness for Container inside Scaffold

Tags: flutter

I need to change the brightness for the Container inside Scaffold, the snippet of code looks like below.
Any hints or suggestions are more than welcome!

PS: I checked document , but the example of changing brightness is for MaterialApp not for Container inside Scaffold.

```
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        title: Text(
          "My Card brightness",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios, color: Colors.white),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Card(
            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 247, 247, 247),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 40),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                // logo
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        child: Container(
                          width: 100,
                          //height: 80,
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                          ),
                          // i need increase brightness here
                          child: Container(
                              width: 90,
                              child: Image.network(
                                '${widget.logo}',
                                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                              )),
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
```

Comment: You can set the `backgroundColor` property of Scaffold to the colour of your liking. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/backgroundColor.html

Comment: I also tried to wrap container into Theme with Brightness.light, but it does not really help

Answer (score 1):

I think changing the brightness of the `Scaffold` *only*, at this moment is still not possible. But, you can add the color to your `Scaffold` and add the opacity to it:

Example:

```
Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(
      "My Card",
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ),
    leading: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios, color: Colors.white),
      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
    ),
  ),
  body: null,
  );
```

**NOTE:** Opacity's value range between 0.0 - 1.0

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `backgroundColor` parameter for `Scaffold` to a different color of your choice.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/backgroundColor.html

```
Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
)
```

Comment: I followed above suggestions already, but it does not help,  what I need is the change brightness of container inside Scaffold

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do. You can change colors, you can't change the actual brightness of the scaffold. To make it appear "brighter", you can make other elements on the page darker.